# Word for mood or (facial) expression if awaiting laughs on a commentary / rhetoric question?

Tags: word-request

Imagine the following (chat) conversation:

> John: Can you name all the presidents?
>   Marry: I thought they already had names ^_^

The text smiley `^_^` - or alternatively `;)` - indicates irony. There are multiple ways to put that answer in spoken language (+countenance):

- dead pan, monotone voice (tends to be sarcastic, may also be an angry, serious answer - no winking smiley in that case)
- slightly grinning, dynamic voice (reply indicates kindly meant joke)
- exaggerated intonation, ending at a high pitch like a (rhetoric) question, with mouth and eyes wide open to indicate that a joyful reaction is expected (and possibly kept until the others get the joke)

Is there a word for the latter? How is this expression or feeling called, waiting for the reaction to the funny answer?

This smiley expresses it quite well:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I'd call that emoticon a "sly smile".

Comment: How about **impish grin**, or **mischievous smile**?

Comment: I disagree with that face up there: That's the Awesome Face, sort of like a I see what you did there kind of deal.

Comment: I think a lot of people use smileys to indicate things other than irony. I use them when I'm smiling :-)

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to mind is: **Whimsical**

```
ADJECTIVE

1.playfully quaint or fanciful, especially in an appealing and amusing way:

"a whimsical sense of humor"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a specific word. I would use **Mischievous**.
In my opinion you described a mischievous facial expressions.